# I M getting wrong output pls help>>>>>

Tags: java, boolean

When I put the value of hourOfDay -1, -2, -3..... the returned value should be false but it is coming true :(

```
package com.company;

public class BarkingDog {
    public static boolean shouldWakeUp(boolean barking, int hourOfDay){
        if(barking && hourOfDay >24 && hourOfDay <0){
            return false;
        }
        else if(barking && hourOfDay < 8 && hourOfDay < 23){
            return true;
        }

    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bacially you are having && operator because of that it happens. read about operators how it works.

Comment: How can ***any*** number be grater than 24 **and** less than zero **at the same time**?

Comment: Actually the int hourOfDay was supposed to have a range of 0-23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you meant to use `||` there instead of `&&`:

```
if (barking && (hourOfDay >24 || hourOfDay <0)) {
    return false;
}
```

Although it seems the entire method can be simplified to a single expression:

```
return barking && hourOfDay > 8 && hourOfDay < 23;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you. Check && is for both conditions and you should use OR ||

```
if (barking && (hourOfDay > 30 || hourOfDay < 0)) {
            return false;
        } else if (barking && hourOfDay < 8 && hourOfDay < 25) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```